# nginx redirect /2013/04/test.html to /test - not working

Tags: linux, nginx, redirect

I've been going mental over this. How can I redirect a certain url like `/2013/04/test.html` to `/test` in nginx?

I have tried this: but doesn't work:

```
server {
     location /2013/05/test.html {
         return 301 http://$server_name/test;
     }
}
```

I've performed some tests - for some reason, any url with no .html extension in the location part of the config line will redirect properly, but as soon as I place .html in the location, kaboom, it stops working.

Any idea why this is? Thank you!

Comment: What actually happens?

Comment: it just doesn't redirect when I put the .html extension. It just ignores it.

Comment: Provide a more detailed config. Just tested - works okay with or without **/2013/05/test.html** existance.

Comment: It was an ordering problem. I included all my redirects before all other location config lines and now everything seems ok!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a location block for each redirect, you can always just add rewrite rules into an existing location block:

```
rewrite /2013/05/test.html http://$server_name/test permanent;
rewrite /2013/05/test2.html http://$server_name/test2 permanent;
```

You can also do various regular expressions so you can avoid from having to add a new one each time a new 'perma-link' is added.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jason Ilicic , using a **rewrite rule** would be probably more efficient.

If you really want to use the **location block** , have you tried using the "=" modifier ? If you have multiple locations Nginx logic of selection might be selecting a different one from what you expect.

From Nginx Documentation

```
using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location
```

so for example

```
server {
    location = /2013/05/test.html {
        return 301 http://$server_name/test;
    }
}
```